# What's this connector pictured called?

Tags: connector, dc, identification

Can anyone identify the connector on the right of the picture?

[image: 12v DC Outwell coolbox connector]

A picture of the same, taken from a different angle:

[image: Better-angle]

Comment: Tried a [Google images search](http://www.google.com/insidesearch/features/images/searchbyimage.html) ?

Comment: @boardbite yes thank you. needless to say I didn't find it. There are alot of connectors...

Comment: Sorry I can't help you, but very interested to know if you found a source for this connector... I am in the same situation, I have a 12v DC powered coolbox which has lost its power cord... Thanks if you can provide any info! Neil.

Comment: Nope, haven't found out what it is yet. My guess is a some china copy. If I find out elsewhere I will post back here the results. Likewise, let us know here if you find out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an R2PPC DC connector, commonly used on mobile R/T equipment and some Kenwood/Trio Comms receivers 20 - 40+ years ago.  Asking for a part for a brand name will always be more expensive than obtaining a generic part (as if you didn't know).  Cheers

Comment: If you had a reference to the dimensions for a R2PPC it would make the answer better and more definitive. Not that I'm especially doubting after a few searches it does look quite similar.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to use the ready made assembly that you had pictured - 
[image]

...with the automotive accessory plug on one end and the unidentified molded job on the other end it may turn out to be more productive for you to simply cut off the end of the cords and attach a more readily available type of connector. One type of plug and jack series to consider would be these:

[image]

There are latchable cable ends, panel mount and PC board mount styles to select.

http://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Kycon/KPJX-PM-3S-S/?qs=sGAEpiMZZMu2f9RNbWupYsheFHL1OiH6%252bfIsWV6Yx1o%3d

Comment: Normally I'd agree but actually it's for a coolbox, it came with a mains adapter and the above car assembly. The car adapter is lost but needed so I was going to make a new one. Problem is the coolbox has the mating end so I can't really change it without it looking a mess.

Answer (score 1):

I have been researching myself, to the point of dismantling my coolbox to see if there are any part numbers etc on the chassis connector - and there weren't. Makes me think this is perhaps a proprietory connector? The only times I have found one on the net they are linked in some way to Waeco portable fridges, and these guys also seem to manufacture for a lot of brands. Might be specific to them?

You can buy spare cig lighter leads with this connector end either from Waeco fridge dealers (be prepared to pay the equiv of US$30+) or from Ebay more reasonable, about US$10.

Here's a [link](http://www.ebay.com/itm/12V-DC-IN-Car-Cooler-Cool-Box-Mini-Fridge-Replacement-2-Pin-Lead-Cable-Plug-2m-/220854946421?pt=UK_Computing_Sound_Vision_Video_Cables_Adapters&hash=item336bfb0a75) for an auction in progress.

He ships worldwide and is charging about US$7 for a made up lead.

Prob the best way to go my friend!

On the other hand, you could do what I did and solder a little flylead on the rear of the DC connector, with a standard type DC socket on the other end. Poked it out of a vent hole easily and tied a knot for strain relief... I did that and it works a treat, if I get round to buying a proper lead I can chop it off and make it look nice again.

Fridge back in action for the next fishing trip and the beer is cooling!

Comment: Thanks for the research, I'd come to think it was proprietory too. Got one from Amazon marketplace similar to the Ebay Auction but locally in the UK.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it looks like the Kenwood plug. I've measure one:

Drawing vs measurement:

14mm => 13.2mm , 5mm => 5.7mm

Total thickness 7.74mm. Distance between the contacts 7mm

Be aware the CB connector is a bit smaller:
Distance between the contacts only 6mm.
Also it has rounded sides.

Kenwood socket (rear of TR-7200G):
[image]
Kenwood connector:
[image]

On the connector it reads : AC 250V 1.5A
Suppose it was legal those days...

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an IEC 60320 connector.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEC_60320

[image]

Comment: It's not notched top and bottom so can't be that, better angle here:

[link](http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51HFEWBCJRL.jpg)

Comment: In your picture it is not so clear if you are showing two sizes of connector OR if you are holding two of the same with one a lot closer to the camera than the other. Without clarification the picture could be confusing - at least it was to me.

Comment: 2nd pic has a smaller connector too, I'm not holding it by the way neither did I take the pic. I'm referring to the 1st pic which has dimensions, the 2nd just gave a better view of the socket pins and notches