# Identify this 2-pin DC connector

Tags: identification, connector, adapter

I'm looking for the power adapter for a dehumidifier (Zibro Clima D4) described in the specs as a **CE approved 220-240 V, AC/DC 13 V/5 A power adapter**, which is shown in [the manual](https://data2.manualslib.com/docimages/i3/58/5704/570308-zibro/28-d4.jpg) and partially shown in this [picture](https://assets.hnvi.nl/files/products/31171/335-vochtregulator-zibro-clima.jpg).

However, I don't know if the two-pin socket is standard. It looks a little like a polarized IEC C7 connector, but it's square on both pin sides, measuring 14 mm x 8 mm, without the top edge lip, like this:

[image: connector profile]

Which search terms do I need to use to find this online?

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE but please note that direct shopping questions will result in fairly prompt closure of your question as per [site rules](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).  See if the C11 on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEC_60320 is close.

Comment: A close up *clear* picture of the actual socket along with some physical measurements would get you a lot farther here.

Comment: Also, look at this question:https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/393775/how-do-i-identify-a-what-kind-of-power-connector-for-ac-mains-is-on-a-product/393776#393776

Comment: Thanks for the response. I forgot about help pages, and expected to find the site rules on the meta site. Unfortunately I can't take a clear picture. I added measurements to the question.

Comment: Oh, and the C11 is AC. Sorry if the comparison to C7 is misleading. I'm looking for a DC connector/adapter. Someone suggested it could be a server connector. I've spend many, many, hours scrolling through images.

Comment: This question was already asked in 2014. see https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/40020/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is late, I just started looking for it. It is a R2PPC 2-pin 13.8VDC connector.

Answer (score 3):

A dehumidifier like this is similar to car refrigeration appliances. Searching for "*power cord for car refrigerator"* leads to results of the correct "B-type plug socket" (a search term suggested by [RobertFay](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/198693/robert-fay)). However, searches for *"Car C7"*, *"IEC 320 C7"* and/or *"Type B"* in popular search engines did not include the correct socket on my account.

Here is a technical drawing (taken from [here](https://www.lazada.com.ph/products/dc12v-24v-power-cord-for-car-refrigerator-car-plug-with-fuseto-c7-b-type-socket-full-copper-extension-cable-for-cooling-and-heating-box-cigeratte-lighter-18m3m4m5m-i406454314-s975662343.html)).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Probably way too late, but I've finally found the perfect match, on Amazon of all places. It's a cigarette lighter DC power plug.

[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B0762JLR6R/ref=ox_sc_act_title_1?smid=A36NNMA87BVHX4&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0762JLR6R)

Answer (score 1):

It almost seems like something that would take a polarized C7 in a non polarized fashion. If you have this I would say it is likely a custom / non-standard connector. 
[image]

Comment: Happened accross this site. No measurments but matches. The call it a B-Type Plug Socket. https://www.dhgate.com/product/universal-d-tap-male-female-connector-anton/416145343.html

Comment: Thanks! I was looking for B-type, and I found this: https://www.lazada.com.ph/products/dc12v-24v-power-cord-for-car-refrigerator-car-plug-with-fuseto-c7-b-type-socket-full-copper-extension-cable-for-cooling-and-heating-box-cigeratte-lighter-18m3m4m5m-i406454314-s975662343.html

Comment: (scroll down to [this picture](https://my-live-01.slatic.net/p/55f09f35ef124db29c16fb94fa143b9d.jpg))

Comment: I'll accept your answer, if you include these search terms end expand on different B-Type Plug Sockets. Specifically, if the one I linked is standard in any way, and maybe why a product would be fitted with anything else than a barrel type connector.

Answer (score 1):

As someone else has already said, this appears to be an R2PPC plug also used in radio communications.  Its also know as a Philmore 8464 plug.  I do believe that the Cybernet CB-2 lead for CB radios etc will fit.  This plug has rounded corners, but the square cornered sockets should match.  The ready made leads may only be rated at 3 amps though. I've seen loose square plugs available on the US ebay site for about $4, but postage and import charges take that cost to $30 to ship out of the US. If it is an IEC C11 plug to match the C12 socket, then the IEC have apparently withdrawn them.  There are still C11 plugs moulded onto lengths of cable on Aliexpress.